# arrayList.contains doesn't invoke overrided equals

Tags: java, object, arraylist

In PacMan DFS problem i represent each points with the following static inner class

```
static class Point{
    int xp;
    int yp;
    public Point(int x, int y){
        xp = x; 
        yp = y;
    }
    public boolean equals(Point p){
        return (xp == p.x && yp == p.y) ? true: false;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return xp+" "+yp;
    }
}
```

and add each point in `ArrayList<Point> points = ArrayList<Point>();`

problem is: if i do the following `points.contains(new Point(1, 2))` equals(method) never invoked although points.size() > 0; (sure)

in case you don't know: contains invoke ArrayList.indexOf --> run though each point and compare by using equals if equals return num>-1 else return -1, but indexOf never reach equals in contains(point) if point is null.

what do you think might be the reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `equals(Point)` is not the one you should create.

Instead you should override `public boolean equals(Object obj)`.

If you would use an `@Override` annotation compiler would inform you that you are trying to override a method but are actually creating an *overloaded* one.

Comment: yeah, that is true. i didn't notice! thanx

Comment: i never forget @Override annotation again.